# Anorm - load the records in a Vector instead of a list

Tags: scala, anorm

Is there an easy way to load the records in a Vector[T] instead of a List[T].

All the examples that I can find on the [docs](http://playframework.github.io/anorm/) return records in List objects.

Thanks

Comment: You may able to write your own method that produces a `Vector`. See the [`ResultSetParser#list`](https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/416e8ceb081baa92fd4b105f2c975c490490f31e/core/src/main/scala/anorm/SqlParser.scala#L599) method for inspiration.